# QFile && QTextStream: как читать файл cp1251 построчно?

Tags: c++, cp1251, qt6

В Qt6  был депрекирован QTextCodec, и теперь нужно использовать QStringConverter. Но QStringConverter не имеет поддержки cp1251 (или я проглядел?), что заставляет возвращаться к QTextCodec. Но вот класс QTextStream раньше имел метод setCodec, а теперь не имеет, даже в режиме совместимости с Qt5. А только setEncoding(QStringConverter::Enconding), который не работает с cp1251.

А в более глобальных смыслах, мне нужно было процедурку чтения файла по строчно, которая работает примерно так:

```
    QFile file(fn);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream in(&file);
    in.setCodec("cp1251");
    while (!in.atEnd())
       task(in.readLine());
```

Как в Qt6 прочитать файл средствами этого Qt в кодировке cp1251 и в других кодировках как было в Qt5 построчно?

Comment: Если вы под windows попробуйте `setEncoding(QStringConverter::System)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня нет qt6, чтобы проверить, но вы всё ещё можете читать строки в `QByteArray` и вручную использовать на них `QTextCodec`.

Например:

```
QFile file("myfile.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
QStringList list;
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
while (true) {
    QByteArray arr = file.readLine();
    if (arr.size() > 0) {
        list << codec->toUnicode(arr);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

А ещё обратите внимание, что `QStringConverter::System` использует системную кодировку, что можно использовать в некоторых ситуациях. Результат работы в таком случае будет аналогичен вызову `QString::fromLocal8Bit(arr)`, т.к. этот метод в qt6 использует `QStringDecoder` с вышеуказанным параметром.

Comment: Можно еще вот так:

file.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream.setEncoding(QStringConverter::Encoding::System);